# Validate a textboth for lengh in angular in Angular form

Tags: regex, angular, validation

I want to validate if the length of data in a text box is either 7 or 10 digits.
If it is not either of those, I want to throw an error message.

```
this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  mytextBox: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[0-9]{7}')]]
});
```

The above pattern is working only if it is 7 digits, how do I add check if it is exactly 7 or 10 digits

Comment: Try an alternation `^(?:[0-9]{10}|[0-9]{7})$` or perhaps check the length of the string and if it consists of digits.

Comment: @Thefourthbird It worked. Thank you!